# Filling a dropdown list with the names of an enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum LeadSoldCreditReasons
{
    [Value(Name = "Incorrect contact information")]
    BadContactInfo = 1,

    [Value(Name = "Not a Real Person")]
    NotRealPerson  =2,

    [Value(Name = "Does not match my filters")]
    FilterMismatch = 3,

    [Value(Name = "Seller Never Requested a Quote")]
    QuoteNotRequested = 4,

    [Value(Name = "Other")]
    Other = 5
}
```

First, I'm not sure if I'm doing the `Name` thing right.  If not, lemme know.

Second, I can fill a dropdown with the enu, values like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CreditReason", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(LeadSoldCreditReasons)), "Select a Reason", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But that gets me this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="MyType" name="MyType"><option value="">Select My Type</option>
    <option value="1">BadContactInfo</option>
    <option value="2">NotRealPerson</option>
    <option value="3">FilterMismatch</option>
    <option value="4">QuoteNotRequested</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

I've tried using `Enum.GetName()` and Enum.GetNames()`, but I either I'm not doing it right, or this isn't the correct way to get this done.

This:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CreditReason", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Enum.GetNames(typeof(LeadSoldCreditReasons))), "Select a Reason", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Gets me this:

> Can not convert string[] to System.Type

Which I guess makes sense because `EnumHelper.GetSelectList()` wants a type.

This:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CreditReason", EnumHelper.GetSelectList(Enum.GetName(typeof(LeadSoldCreditReasons))), "Select a Reason", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Gets me this:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter .. blah blah

Which also makes sense because Enum.GetName() needs two parameters, one is the type, and the other is the instance in the type.

I'm kinda out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `enum`, innstead of `[Value(Name = "Incorrect contact information")]` try `[Display(Name = "Incorrect contact information")]`

> Note: The `Display` attribute is found in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace

Comment: Nailed it!  Thank you also for the namespace!!!  I'll mark as the answer in 5 minutes with it lets me!